# Error in fetching data from xmltype

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error, xmltype

I am new to `XMLTYPE` data handling, so it may just be a very simple query which I am unable to figure out. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Error I am getting while trying with the below code.

```
ORA-06550: line 28, column 54:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 22, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 29, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
```

Here is my code.

```
DECLARE
     x XMLTYPE :=XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
                         <person>   
                         <row>       
                         <name>Tom</name>       
                         <Address>           
                         <State>California</State>           
                         <City>Los angeles</City>       
                         </Address>   
                         </row>   
                         <row>       
                         <name>Jim</name>       
                         <Address>           
                         <State>California</State>           
                         <City>Los angeles</City>       
                         </Address>   
                         </row>                         
                         </person>');
     l_city VARCHAR2(20);
     l_state VARCHAR2(20);
     l_name VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

     SELECT EXTRACT(VALUE(p),'//name/text()')          AS "Name",
         extract(value(p),'/Address//State/text()') AS "State",
         extract(value(p),'/Address//City/text()')  AS "City"
     FROM   dual,
         TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(x,'//person/row/'))) p;
END;
```

Comment: You just have a syntax error. In PL/SQL you have to use `SELECT INTO`. Please refer to Oracle PL/SQL documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below. Please note, in your case XMLSEQUENCE is giving you VARRAY of top level nodes, hence INTO alone may not suffice.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE l_obj IS RECORD
   (
      name    VARCHAR2 (200),
      state   VARCHAR2 (200),
      city    VARCHAR2 (200)
   );

   TYPE l_list_table IS TABLE OF l_obj;

   l_list   l_list_table;
   x        XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE ('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<person>   
<row>       
<name>Tom</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>   
<row>       
<name>Jim</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>
</person>');
BEGIN
   SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '//name/text()'),
          EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '//Address/State/text()'),
          EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '//Address/City/text()')
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_list --please use LIMIT clause
     FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x, '/person/row/*'))) p;

   FOR idx IN l_list.FIRST .. l_list.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_list(idx).name ||', '|| l_list (idx).state || ', ' || l_list (idx).city);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks .   Would you please kindly explain why we are using "*" in this case FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x, '/person/row/*'))) p;

Comment: sorry, not able to a "". Please elaborate. If you are talking about XMLSEQUENCE, then this Oracle doc may help you [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions226.htm)

Comment: Sorry My bad!  I was trying to mean why you are using " * "  in (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x, '/person/row/*'))) p;
Also please explain why are you taking "person/row/" , Is it for the reason that it contains all the child nodes?  Please explain

Comment: That's true. You are receiving a collection under /person/row. * is just a wild card.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select from `DUAL` table, instead you can directly query from `XMLSEQUENCE` function. You can try with the below query.

```
 SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p),'//name') AS "Name",
        EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p),'//Address/State') AS "State",
        EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p),'//Address/City')  AS "City"
 INTO   ..
 FROM   TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(x,'//person/row')))p;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
WITH xx AS (SELECT xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<person>   
<row>       
<name>Tom</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>   
<row>       
<name>Jim</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>
</person>') col1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACT(VALUE(p), '//name/text()') AS "Name",
       EXTRACT(VALUE(p), '//Address//State/text()') AS "State",
       EXTRACT(VALUE(p), '//Address//City/text()') AS "City"
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT((SELECT t1.col1
                                    FROM xx t1),
                                 '//person/row'))) p;
```

or using the COLMUN_VALUE pseudo-colmun:

```
WITH xx AS (SELECT xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<person>   
<row>       
<name>Tom</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>   
<row>       
<name>Jim</name>       
<Address>           
<State>California</State>           
<City>Los angeles</City>       
</Address>   
</row>
</person>') col1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACT(column_value, '//name/text()') AS "Name",
       EXTRACT(column_value, '//Address//State/text()') AS "State",
       EXTRACT(column_value, '//Address//City/text()') AS "City"
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT((SELECT t1.col1
                                    FROM xx t1),
                                 '//person/row')));
```

I hope it helps. 
Cyryl